# Fancybox working on local but has gliches on server

Tags: fancybox

I am new at fancybox and am having trouble. I think I have done it right, according to what the fancybox site says. I have a few images and wanted to hide all but one and then have a slide show. This worked great when I was working local but now it is missing a bunch of styling it seems and it is not hiding the other images.
Here is one of the pages:
http://josborneanderson.com/design/farmers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing this file on your server.

http://josborneanderson.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5

Comment: I adjusted it by taking off the ?v=2.1.5 so it matches what i have loaded but still is not working properly. My file server shows it as loaded

Comment: @Jenn : what Bill means is that the fancybox files http://josborneanderson.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js and http://josborneanderson.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css are NOT there. Check the exact path of each file.

Comment: The folder "fancybox" had a capitol B. Thanks for the help!